# Troubles converting XSD to Java using JAXB

Tags: xsd, jaxb

I'm trying to convert an XSD I have no control over to Java classes using JAXB.  The errors I'm getting are :

```
[ERROR] cvc-pattern-valid: Value 'true' is not facet-valid with respect to pattern '0|1' for type 'BooleanType'.
  line 139 of http://neon/meaweb/schema/common/meta/MXMeta.xsd

[ERROR] a-props-correct.2: Invalid value constraint value '1' in attribute 'mxencrypted'.
  line 139 of http://neon/meaweb/schema/common/meta/MXMeta.xsd
```

The code in the XSD that contains the error is in:

```
  <xsd:complexType name="MXCryptoType">
    <xsd:simpleContent>
      <xsd:extension base="xsd:base64Binary">
        <xsd:attribute name="changed" type="ChangeIndicatorType" use="optional" />
        <xsd:attribute name="mxencrypted" type="BooleanType" use="optional" default="1" />
      </xsd:extension>
    </xsd:simpleContent>
```

Specifically it's the attribute mxencrypted using the BooleanType.  BooleanType is defined as

```
  <xsd:simpleType name="BooleanType">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:boolean">
      <xsd:pattern value="0|1" />
    </xsd:restriction>
  </xsd:simpleType>
```

From searching around this seems to be a somewhat common case.  From what I can tell the default in the mxencrypted line shouldn't be a 1? When I load the XSD into Liquid XML, the schema doesn't report errors.  Validating the XSD here (http://www.utilities-online.info/xsdvalidation/#.UV3zkL_EW0s) reports the same errors as JAXB.

Is there a way to tell JAXB to ignore this problem and just generate the class ignoring the default?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8975834/invalid-constraint-value) (and I've just updated it with relevant information). I am not aware of a way to tell JAXB to ignore it, since this error happens in the XSD schema processor (before JAXB's xjc starts to do its work actually).

The only way may be to filter out the default attributes; however, in this case it is obvious that the XSD designer intended to have a default value of true, which would not be the case with your generated code (Java defaults to false).

This could yield unwanted fracas, my recommendation would be to work with the XSD provider to get it fixed.

Maybe a sidebar, but I personally consider the use of defaults in XSDs as an *interoperability monster* : any XML processor that is not relying on the XSD would behave differently than one that does.